# Getting pixel space coordinates correct for an image capture in Unity

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, coordinate-systems, getpixel

I'm wanting to set up an area on my screen for a screen capture using ReadPixels but I'm unsure how the pixel space coordinates. Based on a 825 x 825 pixel square that is 215 pixels from the left and 134 pixels up from the bottom. How would I enter that in to ReadPixels parameters. I've entered my guess in the line below. Is that correct or does y need to be negative?

```
TmpTexture2D.ReadPixels(new Rect(215, 134, 1040, 959), 0, 0, false);
```

[image]

Comment: What are you capturing? You can use `RenderTexture` and get the entire rendered image.

Comment: Well I have a coloring book application that allows a user to draw and I only want to capture that particular area.

Comment: You can get the bound's of your points (i assume you are using a 2D Camera) and use that bounds as a rect to crop the image.

Comment: Just added a diagram to better illustrate

Comment: I was previously capturing my entire screen using `TmpTexture2D.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, RenderTextureSize.x, RenderTextureSize.y), 0, 0, false);` but I only need to capture an area and the application will always be running at a 1280x1024 screen resolution.

Comment: As i understand you are drawing onto a texture? Do you want the user to draw a `rectangle` to get the region or are you trying to come up with a `heuristic` that it automatically should detect `painted` and `non-painted` areas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159955/discussion-between-greybow-and-user1767754).